# Export to Excel with empty cells as dilimiters

Tags: list-manipulation, export

I would like to combine some pieces of data and export the data to Excel, but I need to insert some empty cells between pieces of data as the delimiter. For example, I have two lists `listA={1,2,3}, listB={4,5,6}`, and I want to add two empty cells between the two parts to look like this in the exported Excel file

[image]

One way I can think of is to include some empty items in the final list to export, e.g., `listFinal={1, 2, 3, , , 4, 5, 6}`, then `Export[filepath + name, listFinal]`. But I could not figure out how to produce `listFinal` from `listA` and `listB` with those empty items inserted. Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Null` for the empty elements e.g.

```
Export["foo.xlsx", listA~Join~{Null, Null}~Join~listB]
```

[image]